# Sequelize Error: The dialect [object Object] is not supported when running migrations

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, migration

I'm currently facing a major issue while trying to run migrations with Sequelize and could really use some assistance. The problem I'm encountering is as follows:

After configuring Sequelize settings both in the `.sequelizerc` file and `src/config/database.js` file, I attempt to run `npx sequelize db:migrate`, but I encounter the following error message:

`ERROR: The dialect [object Object] is not supported. Supported dialects: mssql, mariadb, mysql, oracle, postgres, db2, and sqlite.`

Here are the relevant configuration files for reference:

`.sequelizerc` file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  config: path.resolve('src/config/database.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('src/models'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/migrations'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/seeders'),
};
```

`src/config/database.js` file:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  }
);

module.exports = sequelize;
```

I have tried copying the exact code from the documentation [see here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/) and still ran into the same bug.

My expectation is that when I run the `npx sequelize db:migrate` command the tables in my migration files would be created in the database

Here's my `package.json` file in case it provides additional insights:

```
{
  "name": "viking-event-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint --fix src",
    "test": "jest",
    "migrate:up": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "migrate:undo": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.33.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.1"
  }
}
```

I've researched their documentation and various other sources but haven't come across a solution. Any assistance in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The indicated module `path.resolve('src/config/database.js')` should return the configuration and not a connection instance